# How to use firebase timestamp with graphql nest js?

Tags: firebase, graphql, nestjs, apollo

All dates in firebase are stored as timestamps, no matter how do you store them: as ISO string, or just as `new Date()`.

But I don't want to send `firestore.Timestamp` instance on the client side, so I need to somehow serialize it.

What are the options? How can I send only ISO string, or unix time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Simpliest and dumbest solution

Store date using unix time:

```
const newItem = {
  ...,
  createdAt: Date.now(),
};

itemsCollection.add(newItem);
```

this way it will be stored as plain `number` and it can be converted back to normal date using `new Date()`

### 2. Use third-party library (worked only for schema first approach for me)

[firestore-graphql-scalars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-graphql-scalars) contains [scalar](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/scalars/) type definitions and resolvers for firebase timestamp

If you are going for scheme-first approach it works perfectly fine, **but I couldn't find a way to use it in Nest JS GraphQL code first approach**

### 3. Define new scalar type yourself (code first approach implementation)

At the end I came up with this scalar using code first approach:

```
@Scalar('FirebaseTimestamp')
export class FirebaseTimestampScalar implements CustomScalar<number, admin.firestore.Timestamp> {
  description = 'Firebase timestamp';

  parseValue(milliseconds: number): admin.firestore.Timestamp {
    return admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(milliseconds); // value from the client
  }

  serialize(timestamp: admin.firestore.Timestamp): number {
    return timestamp.toMillis(); // value sent to the client
  }

  parseLiteral(ast: ValueNode): admin.firestore.Timestamp {
    if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
      return admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Number(ast.value));
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

and in data type:

```
@ObjectType()
export class DocumentMeta implements IDocumentMeta {
  @Field(() => ID)
  createdBy: string;
  @Field(() => ID)
  updatedBy: string;
  @Field(() => FirebaseTimestampScalar)
  createdAt: Date;
  @Field(() => FirebaseTimestampScalar)
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

P.S. Don't forget to add this scalar to resolver module providers

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    ...resolvers,
    FirebaseTimestampScalar,
  ],
})
export class ResolversModule {}
```

you still have to convert it to date on client side, but on server side it remains as `Timestamp` instance, so it looks a little bit cleaner

### 5. Worth mentioning, but maybe not so useful

If you still think you need to get `Timestamp` 'as is' on client-side, you can stringify timestamp object, and parse it on client

You can do it yourself or using [graphql-type-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-json)